# Angular 5/6 Http get call

Tags: angular

I am trying to make Spotify app using MEAN Stack. For Spotify OAuth I have a sample code in nodeJS that spotify provides. I am new to making http calls and server side code. In the below image it shows that it uses res.redirect() which I suppose that redirection is get response. How can I do that in angular 5/6 service class? The below code shows how I was trying. I am not sure what to put inside get brackets as well.

[image]

```
spotifyOAuth() {
    var uri = this.loginURI()
    return this.http.get('/spotifyLogIn')
    .map((res:Response) => res.redirected(uri));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `subscribe()` instead of `map()`.